# TFS build does not produce assembly only log folders in drop folder

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I setup automated build on TFS with visual studio 2013. For some reason, in the drop folder, I only see the log folders but not built libraries. Any ideas what could be wrong. I see the message below in the log files, and I have tried so many combinations editing the .vbproj file. There are no errors from the build.

Build succeeded.

```
"C:\Builds\88263\soft_Collection\Flight\src\Sigma_2014\ExcelIn\Process\Process.vbproj" (default target) (1) ->
(_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform target) -> 

  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(610,5): warning : The OutputPath property is not set for project Process.vbproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Release'  Platform='Any CPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project. [C:\Builds\88263\soft_Collection\Flight\src\Sigma_2014\ExcelIn\Process\Process.vbproj]

    1 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

Contents of vbproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">Any CPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>9.0.30729</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{E2C59301-D7EC-4734-A6CD-57FCDABFEEF8}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>SFAutomation</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>SFAutomation</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <MyType>Windows</MyType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <OptionExplicit>On</OptionExplicit>
    <OptionCompare>Binary</OptionCompare>
    <OptionStrict>Off</OptionStrict>
    <OptionInfer>On</OptionInfer>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>sfautomation.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile>
    </TargetFrameworkProfile>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|Any CPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <DefineDebug>true</DefineDebug>
        <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
        <OutputPath>..\..\..\..\bin\debug\</OutputPath>
        <DocumentationFile>SFAutomation.xml</DocumentationFile>
        <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022,42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
        <RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
        <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|Any CPU' ">
        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <DefineDebug>false</DefineDebug>
        <DefineTrace>true</DefineTrace>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DocumentationFile>SFAutomation.xml</DocumentationFile>
        <NoWarn>42016,41999,42017,42018,42019,42032,42036,42020,42021,42022,42353,42354,42355</NoWarn>
        <RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
        <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
      </PropertyGroup

>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get around this is to just build a solution file instead of directly referencing a project file.